# compiling issue with constructor in c++

Tags: c++, compilation

I'm having a bad time with this issue because I cannot resolve it. I've designed a matrix template class and a pixel class and now I'd like to join them but I'm not been able to accomplish the task.

The error I'm having is the following:

```
pgm_matrix.cpp: In constructor ‘PGMmatrix::PGMmatrix(unsigned int, unsigned int)’:
pgm_matrix.cpp:13:23: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
          Matrix<Pixel>* m(l, h);
                               ^
pgm_matrix.cpp:13:23: error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned int’ to ‘Matrix<Pixel>*’ [-fpermissive]
```

My Pixel.hpp:

```
#ifndef __PIXEL_HPP__
#define __PIXEL_HPP__

class Pixel
{
    private:
            int posx_;
            int posy_;
            unsigned int intensity_;

        public:
            Pixel();
            Pixel(int, int, unsigned int);  
            Pixel(Pixel const &);
            ~Pixel();

            bool operator==(const Pixel &)const;
            bool operator!=(const Pixel &)const;
            Pixel const &operator=(Pixel const &);
            void operator()(int, int, unsigned int);

            int get_pixel_pos_x() const;
            int get_pixel_pos_y() const;
            unsigned int get_pixel_intensity() const;
    };

    #endif
```

My matrix.hpp:

```
#ifndef __MATRIX_HPP__
#define __MATRIX_HPP__

template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
    private:
        T** matrix_;
        unsigned int rows_;
        unsigned int cols_;

    public:
        Matrix();
        Matrix(unsigned int, unsigned int);
        Matrix(Matrix const &);
        ~Matrix();

        bool operator==(const Matrix &)const;
        bool operator!=(const Matrix &)const;
        Matrix const &operator=(Matrix const &);
        T &operator()(unsigned int, unsigned int);
        T const &operator()(unsigned int, unsigned int) const;

        T& data(unsigned int, unsigned int);
        T const &data(unsigned int, unsigned int) const;

        unsigned int const get_rows()const;
        unsigned int const get_cols()const;

};

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix() : matrix_(0), rows_(0), cols_(0)
{
}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols)
{
    matrix_ = new T*[rows];
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < rows; i++)
        matrix_[i] = new T[cols];
    rows_ = rows;
    cols_ = cols;
}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(Matrix<T> const & m_orig)
{
    rows_ = m_orig.rows_;
    cols_ = m_orig.cols_;
    matrix_ = new T*[rows_];
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < rows_; i++)
    {
        matrix_[i] = new T[cols_];
        for(unsigned int j=0; j < cols_; j++)
            matrix_[i][j]=m_orig.matrix_[i][j];
    }
}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::~Matrix()
{
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < rows_; i++)
        delete matrix_[i];
    delete matrix_;
    rows_ = 0;
    cols_ = 0;
}

template<typename T>
bool Matrix<T>::operator==(const Matrix & m)const
{
    if(m.cols_ != cols_ || m.rows_ != rows_)
        return false;
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < rows_; i++)
    {
        for(unsigned int j=0; j < cols_; j++)
        {
            if(m.matrix_[i][j] != matrix_[i][j])
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

template<typename T>
bool Matrix<T>::operator!=(const Matrix & m)const
{
    if( m == *this)
        return false;
    return true;
}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T> const &Matrix<T>::operator=(Matrix const & m_orig)
{
    if(this != &m_orig)
    {
        for(unsigned int k=0; k < rows_; k++)
            delete matrix_[k];
        delete matrix_;

        rows_ = m_orig.rows_;
        cols_ = m_orig.cols_;
        matrix_ = new T*[rows_];
        for(unsigned int i=0; i < rows_; i++)
        {
            matrix_[i] = new T[cols_];
            for(unsigned int j=0; j < cols_; j++)
                matrix_[i][j]=m_orig.matrix_[i][j];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
T &Matrix<T>::operator()(unsigned int i, unsigned int j)
{
    return matrix_[i][j];
}

template<typename T>
T const &Matrix<T>::operator()(unsigned int i, unsigned int j) const
{

    return matrix_[i][j];
}

template<typename T>
T& Matrix<T>::data(unsigned int i, unsigned int j)
{
    return matrix_[i][j];
}

template<typename T>
T const &Matrix<T>::data(unsigned int i, unsigned int j) const
{
    return matrix_[i][j];
}

template<typename T>
unsigned int const Matrix<T>::get_rows() const
{
    return rows_;
}

template<typename T>
unsigned int const Matrix<T>::get_cols() const
{
    return cols_;
}


#endif
```

Finally the code that fails:

```
#include "pgm_matrix.hpp"
#include "matrix.hpp"
#include "pixel.hpp"


PGMmatrix::PGMmatrix(unsigned int l, unsigned int h)
{
    large_  = l;
    height_ = h;
    Matrix<Pixel>* m(l, h);
    matrix_ = m;//here is the problem
}

int main()
{
    PGMmatrix p(2,2);
    return 0;
}
```

PGM_matrix.hpp:

```
#ifndef __PGM_MATRIX_HPP__
#define __PGM_MATRIX_HPP__
#include "matrix.hpp"
#include "pixel.hpp"

class PGMmatrix
{
    private:
        Matrix<Pixel>* matrix_;
        unsigned int large_;
        unsigned int height_;

    public:
        PGMmatrix();
        PGMmatrix(unsigned int, unsigned int);
        PGMmatrix(PGMmatrix const &);
        ~PGMmatrix();

        bool operator==(const PGMmatrix &) const;
        bool operator!=(const PGMmatrix &) const;
        PGMmatrix const &operator=(PGMmatrix const &);
        void operator()(int, int, Pixel);

};
#endif
```

to compile I do:

```
g++ pixel.o pgm_matrix.cpp -o pgm
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: What do you think `Matrix<Pixel>* m(l, h);` is doing? What do you intend to do in that line? (Isn't the closing `}` missing in that function?)

Comment: Matrix<Pixel>* m(l, h); is a constructor of Matrix<T> that returns a matrix with l columns and h rows.

Comment: Pointers don't have constructors. Did you mean `Matrix<Pixel> m(l,h);`  If so then `Matrix<Pixel>* matrix_;` should be `Matrix<Pixel> matrix_;`

Comment: RIGHT! that was the problem. thanks Matt! :-)

Comment: BTW, identifiers which begin with two underscores are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Actually, identifiers that have two consecutive underscores *anywhere* (beginning, middle or end) are reserved for the implementation (was beginning only in C, but changed to anywhere in C++).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using 'new' to create a new instance on the heap.

...

```
PGMmatrix::PGMmatrix(unsigned int l, unsigned int h)
{
  large_  = l;
  height_ = h;
  matrix_ = new Matrix<Pixel>(l, h); // Use new, to create a new instance on the heap
}
```

...

Or better do not use a pointer.

...

```
 class PGMmatrix
 {
 private:
   Matrix<Pixel> matrix_;
```

...

Comment: Tanks! I took the first way.